# Not able to access global variable in python rexpro connection

Tags: python

I am trying to create a global variable in rexpro connection which I can use in my subsequent execution calls but the global variable is not working. Below is a simple code snippet.

```
from rexpro import RexProConnection
conn = RexProConnection('localhost', 8184, 'graph')
#number will become a global variable for this session
conn.execute("number = 5")
conn.execute("number")
```

I get the following error when I call the number variable again in my last line

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 5, in <module>
    conn.execute("number")
  File "/opt/savvi-deps/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rexpro/connectors/base.py", line 426, in execute
    response.raise_exception()
  File "/opt/savvi-deps/python27/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rexpro/messages.py", line 198, in raise_exception
    raise exceptions.RexProScriptException(self.message)
rexpro.exceptions.RexProScriptException: An error occurred while processing the script for language [groovy]. All transactions across all graphs in the session have been concluded with failure: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: number for class: Script17
```

What I wanted to have is a management object which I can use latter in my code like below.

```
from rexpro import RexProConnection
conn = RexProConnection('localhost', 8184, 'graph')
#number will become a global variable for this session
conn.execute("mgmt=g.getManagementSystem()")
conn.execute("mgmt.makePropertyKey('name').dataType(String.class).make()")
```

Followed example in this page :http://rexpro-python.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html

Answer (score 0):

Finally cracked it. By default the isolate option seems to be true which encapsulate the variable to be used in next line. The following code works.

```
from rexpro import RexProConnection
conn = RexProConnection('localhost', 8184, 'graph')
#number will become a global variable for this session
conn.execute("number = 5",isolate=False)
conn.execute("number")
```